# PL/SQL FETCH into data string

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm new to oracle forms and i have a problem i hope you might help me to resolve.

My question is there a way to put data fetched into a data string?
For example here i use dbms_output, but is there a way to put all rows into data string separated by ';'?
So ideally result should look something like 'engineer;manager;database analyst;'

Thank you

```
DECLARE 
 Job_desc varchar(100);

CURSOR cur_job is 
      SELECT job_id
from job a  where a.salary='10000';
BEGIN 
   OPEN cur_job; 
   LOOP 
   FETCH cur_job into job_desc;
      EXIT WHEN cur_job%notfound; 
      dbms_output.put_line(job_desc || ';'); 
   END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is Forms, you'd do something like this (based on Scott's EMP table):

```
declare
  job_desc varchar2(100);
begin
  for cur_r in (select distinct job 
                from emp
                where sal > 1000
               )
  loop
    job_desc := job_desc ||';'|| cur_r.job;
  end loop;
end;
```

Now it depends on what you want to do with `job_desc`:

- display it as a message on the screen (two consecutive `message` calls; otherwise, it would be displayed in the status line)

  ```
  end loop;
  message(job_desc);
  message(job_desc);
  ```

  (alternatively, see how **alerts** work)
- put it into block item:

  ```
  end loop;
  :block.job_description := job_desc;
  ```

  But, for this option, you'd rather directly put jobs into the item, not into the variable and then into the item.

---

I don't know whether Forms 10 support `listagg`; if so, it would be even simpler:

```
select listagg(job, ';') within group (order by null) job_desc
from (select distinct job
      from emp
      where sal > 1000
     );
```

If not, xmlagg works:

```
select rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, job || ', ') order by job).extract 
               ('//text()'), ', ')
from (select distinct job
      from emp
      where sal > 1000
     );
```

---

So, quite a few options; pick one.

Comment: Forms - even later versions - do not support most (any?) of the 11g features and listagg is one of them.
There is another workaround - you can use user defined aggregates, so you can implement your own listagg (the limitation is you can't use 'within group order by' clause, you would have to hardcode order by clause inside implementation), or if you don't want to implement your own aggregate, undocumented wm_concat aggregate is provided, as long as you're fine with comma as separator.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, you saved me once again. I used first option, worked beautifully. Unfortunately  listagg is not supported in my forms.